# Нужна ли запятая перед «пусть»?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

И(,) пусть я прилетела на вокзал вовремя, здорово, что поезд ушёл.

Answer (score 1):

Правильно: ***И пусть я прилетела на вокзал вовремя, здорово, что поезд ушёл.***

Запятая на стыке союзов не ставится, союз И **присоединительный**.

1. Правило:   [§ 36. Запятая на стыке двух союзов](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=140#pp140)

Пункт 5. Постановка запятой между присоединительным союзом (в начале предложения, после точки) и следующим за ним подчинительным союзом зависит **от значения союза**:

(1) как правило, после союза И запятая не ставится:  *И хотя погода значительно улучшилась, опасность засухи не миновала.*

2. Из словаря: **ПУСТЬ** II. союз. (обычно в составе сложноподчинённого предл.). 1. Выражает уступительное допущение при противопоставлении; допустим, положим, готов согласиться.

Answer (score 0):

Запятая ставится.

И, пусть я прилетела на вокзал вовремя, здорово, что поезд ушёл.

1. «Пусть» в данном случае — это не частица, а союз со значением «хотя».
2. Если в сложном предложении рядом оказались сочинительный и подчинительный союзы (И и ХОТЯ, И и КАК и др.), то нужно выяснить, нет ли после придаточной части соотносительных слов ТО, ТАК или еще одного сочинительного союза (А, НО, ОДНАКО и др.). Запятая ставится только тогда, когда эти слова после придаточной части отсутствуют.(Грамота.ру)